# How can we display hidden files without using ls command?

Tags: unix

Is there another way to display hidden files in the current directory without the using the `ls -a` command?

Comment: Not in command line. If you're talking about how to do it in your window manager, it depends on the one you use.

Comment: -1 Why do you want to do this? Please provide an example or what you want/need to achieve, otherwise this question is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it might work:

> tree -a.

Also, you can always add alias:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> $la

This command worked same as  ls -a

Comment: this was probably an alias